# Как в python input передать содержимое текстового файла

Tags: python, windows

у меня есть `python` скрипт

```py
a = input();
a = a + ' привет'
print(a);
```

Я хочу из командной строки `Windows 10` дать ему прочитать содержимое текстового файла, как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В командной строке нужно вызывать так: `py pythonfile.py < text.txt`

Answer (score 5):

```
import os
import sys
if len(sys.argv) == 2:    
    raw_path = sys.argv[1] #получается аргумент командной строки
    path = raw_path.replace('\\', '/').replace('"',"") #\ меняется на /, убираем ""
    f = open(path, 'r')
    info = f.read()
    f.close()
    print("Содержимое файла\n", info)
else:
    print("Не указан путь!")

os.system("pause")
```

Теперь если в командной строке написать `test.py "C:\Users\Пользователь\Desktop\Python\input.txt"` Мы получим содержимое файла по этому пути. А если просто test.py - Не указан путь!

Answer (score 3):

для примера создадим файл `123.txt`, в том же каталоге где и `test.py`, с содержимым:
*это файл 123.txt*

```
a = input('введите путь к файлу')
b = open(a, 'rb').read().decode('utf-8')
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from sys import argv 
filename=argv 
file=open(filepath+".txt",mode="r")
print(file.read()+"привет")
```

Тут надо запускать с командной строки с параметром после пути

Comment: я бы хотел из командной строки

Comment: @МихаилКамахин в смысле из командной строки выбирать имя файла или вы хотите питоновские комады в командной строке windows использовать

Comment: Я бы хотел использовать команды командной строки и дать питоновскому файлу на поток ввода текст из текстового файла

Comment: @МихаилКамахин если из командной строки это test.py "C:\Users\Пользователь\Desktop\Python\input.txt" - смотрите у ответ

Answer (score 1):

Если вы имеете ввиду чтение из текстового файла, то вот:

```
f = open("Название файла.txt")
a = f.read()
a = a + " привет"
print(a)
```

Comment: Важно отметить, что текстовый файл должен находиться в той же папке, что и .py файл. Иначе нужно указать полный путь до файла